# Cycle2 - using previous/next images for navigation

Tags: jquery-cycle2

I'm struggling to find documentation covering the ability to us actual slide images for navigation. I have a carousel and as well as the standard prev/next option i'd like to be able to click the previous and next images within the carousel. Naturally the logic would be clicking the previous slide to the left of the active slide would send the carousel backwards one slide and clicking the slide to the right of the current active slide would advance the carousel to the next slide.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It seems like it should be straight-forward but none of the demos seem to broach this functionality.

Comment: I've now set up a fiddle to demonstrate this http://jsfiddle.net/randalldon/Q4cqu/. What i'm looking to be able to do is use images to the left and right of the active image to provide the navigation i.e. clicking the image to the left will send the carousel back one image and the image to the right advance the carousel one image.

Comment: OK, seems to have sorted this now. Updated fiddle if anyone's interested http://jsfiddle.net/randalldon/Q4cqu/1/.